# WinDBG: Execute du Command on first arg of top stack automatically

Tags: windbg

I have a breakpoint on some source code set up.
Each time the break point is triggered I execute two commands:

```
0:000> kb 1
 # RetAddr               : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00007ffa`a05db848     : 00007ffa`a061ac98 00007ffa`b3135ba1 000002a8`32f20000 000002a8`32f20000 : KERNELBASE!GetEnvironmentVariableW
```

Pick the first argument address `00007ffa a061ac98` and display it via

```
0:000> du 00007ffa`a061ac98
00007ffa`a061ac98  "InstallRoot"
```

Now basically the break point gets hit everytime and I always have to manually run two commands and a manual copy paste of an address.

Is there a more automatic way?
I've tried `dx` but this does not work for me, as I am missing the parameters

```
0:000> dx -r3 Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.First().Threads.First().Stack.Frames[0]
Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.First().Threads.First().Stack.Frames[0]                 : KERNELBASE!GetEnvironmentVariableW [Switch To]
    LocalVariables   : Unexpected failure to dereference object
    Parameters       : Unexpected failure to dereference object
    Attributes      
        InstructionOffset : 0x7ffab0835240
        ReturnOffset     : 0x7ffaa05db848
        FrameOffset      : 0xce79ffee90
        StackOffset      : 0xce79ffee98
        FuncTableEntry   : 0x0
        Virtual          : 1
        FrameNumber      : 0x0
```

Nor does getting the parameters work

```
0:000> dx -r3 Debugger.Sessions.First().Processes.First().Threads.First().Stack.Frames[0].Parameters
Error: Wrong Parameter. (0x80070057)
```

A hint on how I could extract Arg[0] from top frame and display it more automatically would be great!

Note: I basically want to execute this command each time the break point hits. Maybe there is a better way for this.

Comment: You mean you need to display the value of pointer try dpu esp+offset. Or du poi(esp+offset).  Bp addr "dpu xxxx;gc". Should print  and continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: The first argument is in ebx in my case. So
`du ebx` does the trick!